# Reorganizing mysql aggregate row into single piece rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Consider the following mysql table:

```
ID    WeightS AmountS WeightM AmountM WeightL AmountL Someothercolumnshere
 1         6       3      10       2      18       2                  ...
```

I need to reorganize this data into a pivot-friendly table, where each piece in the amount columns should be one result row. E.g. from the first two columns, WeightS and AmountS, the SELECT should produce 3 result rows, each having a weight of 2 kgs (=6 kgs total). So the full result table should be like this:

```
Weight Someothercolumnshere
     2                ...
     2                ...
     2                ...
     5                ...
     5                ...
     9                ...
     9                ...
```

I don't even know if there's a SQL syntax which is able to do this kind of operation? I've never had a request like this before. Worst case scenario, I have to do it in php instead, but I think MYSQL is a lot more fun :p

I've built the schema on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0de23d), but I'm afraid that's all I've got.

Comment: update you question add  ad proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I've added the schema in an sqlfiddle, and I think the expected result is already in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Tally table for the task like this. Create as much rows as needed in it.

```
 Create table Tally(`N` int);
 insert into Tally( `N`) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Then

```
(select `ID`, `WeightS`/`AmountS`, `Someothercolumnshere`
from Catches
join Tally on Catches.`AmountS` >= Tally.`N`
 ) 
 UNION ALL
 (select `ID`, `WeightL`/`AmountL`, `Someothercolumnshere`
from Catches
join Tally on Catches.`AmountL` >= Tally.`N`
 ) 
 UNION ALL
 (select `ID`, `WeightM`/`AmountM`, `Someothercolumnshere`
from Catches
join Tally on Catches.`AmountM` >= Tally.`N`
 )
```

Comment: Hi Serg, looks like this works perfectly, thank you! I don't quite understand the sql though, can you tell me what the rows in Tally is for? I tried running the select with 7 rows from the initial table (Catches) and only 5 rows in Tally, and it still gave me the correct output. (Which is great, but I want to understand why)

Comment: @aanders77 Tally allows you to repeat a row several times. So it must have a number of rows which is at least the max number of  rows you need for a single ID and one of AmountX columns. For example if AmountS =100 is that maximum, you need 100 rows in Tally.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you very much @Serg!